# ASP.Net, GridView, Подстановка сохранённых значений в строку редактирования

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Вопрос к знатокам. Есть GridView.
[image: GridView]

Вывод, вставка и удаление работают. Алгоритм вставки

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//список со всеми поломками
    {
        ((ListBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ListBox2")).Items.Clear();//чистим второй список

        foreach (ListItem li in ((ListBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ListBox1")).Items)//проходим по первому списку, где есть все элементы
        {
            if (li.Selected)//если элемент выбран
            {
                ((ListBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ListBox2")).Items.Add(li.Text);//бросаем его во второй список для предпросмотра результата(вообще-то для предпросмотра можно использовать лейбл...)
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ListBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//список со всеми механиками
    {
        ((ListBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ListBox4")).Items.Add(((ListBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ListBox3")).SelectedItem.Text);//кидаем выбранного механика
        ((ListBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ListBox3")).SelectedIndex = -1;//снимаем выделение, чтобы одного и того же можно было указать два раза подряд
    }

    protected void ListBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//дает возможность удалить механика в случае ошибки
    {
        ((ListBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ListBox4")).Items.Remove(((ListBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ListBox4")).SelectedItem);
    }

    string breakslist;//переменная для списка поломок, которая отправится в БД
    string workerslist;//переменная для списка механиков
    string priceslist;//для стоимостей ремонта каждой поломки

    protected void Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//кнопка добавления
    {
        breakslist = "";//предварительно обнуляем их  на всякий случай
        workerslist = "";
        priceslist = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;//цены можно сохранить сразу
        foreach (ListItem li in ((ListBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ListBox2")).Items)//пробегаем по второму списку
        {
            breakslist += li.Text + "<br/>";//и сохраняем из него все в одну переменную разделяя названия поломок тегом переноса
        }
        foreach (ListItem li in ((ListBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ListBox4")).Items)//аналогично, как и с поломками
        {
            workerslist += li.Text + "<br/>";
        }
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["breakslist"].DefaultValue = breakslist;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["workerslist"].DefaultValue = workerslist;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["priceslist"].DefaultValue = priceslist;

        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    }
```

Алгоритм получения элементов списка из сохраненной переменной

```
            foreach (GridViewRow Row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataView dview = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            breakslist = (String)dview.Table.Rows[Row.RowIndex]["breakslist"];//получаем переменную из БД

            for (int i = 0; i < breakslist.Length; i++)//посимвольно её перебираем
            {
                if (breakslist[i] != '<')//кидаем символы в строковую переменную пока не наткнемся на начало тега <br/>
                {
                    formItem += breakslist[i];
                }
                else//если же наткнулись, то сохраняем переменную как элемент списка и
                {
                    ((ListBox)GridView1.Rows[Row.RowIndex].FindControl("ListBox6")).Items.Add(formItem);
                    formItem = "";
                    i = i + 4;//и перескакиваем через тег бр
                }
            }
        }
```

Вопрос: куда мне воткнуть второй алгоритм, чтобы элементы списка добавлялись в список во время редактирования ?

[image: В режиме редактирования у меня нет предварительно сохраненных значений]

Пытался с RowDataBound и RowEditing, но потерпел неудачу. Получал *Null Reference Exception* и *ArgumentsOutOfRangeException*, видимо не в тот момент я значения пытался добавить. Асп код таблицы прилагается

```
<%@ Page Title="Чеки" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="checks.aspx.cs" Inherits="autorepair.checks" %>
```

```
<div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:autorepairConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [checks] WHERE [checkID] = @checkID" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [checks] ([breakslist], [workerslist], [priceslist]) VALUES (@breakslist, @workerslist, @priceslist)"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [checks]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [checks] SET [breakslist] = @breakslist, [workerslist] = @workerslist, [priceslist] = @priceslist WHERE [checkID] = @checkID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="checkID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="breakslist" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="workerslist" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="priceslist" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="breakslist" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="workerslist" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="priceslist" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="checkID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:autorepairConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [breakdownID], [breakname] FROM [breakdowns]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:autorepairConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [workerID], [fullname] FROM [workers] WHERE [position]='Механик'">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="checkID"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" ShowFooter="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="checkID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("checkID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("checkID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="Insert_Click" runat="server">Добавить</asp:LinkButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Поломки" SortExpression="breakdown1">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox6" runat="server" Rows="5" Width="132px"></asp:ListBox>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                        DataTextField="breakname" DataValueField="breakdownID" Rows="5" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("breakslist") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" Rows="5" Width="132px"></asp:ListBox>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                        DataTextField="breakname" DataValueField="breakdownID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        Rows="5" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Механик" SortExpression="worker1">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox8" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Rows="5" Width="132px"></asp:ListBox>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox7" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
                        DataTextField="fullname" DataValueField="workerID" Rows="5"></asp:ListBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("workerslist") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox4_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        Rows="5" Width="132px"></asp:ListBox>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
                        DataTextField="fullname" DataValueField="workerID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox3_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        Rows="5"></asp:ListBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Стоимость ремонта" SortExpression="price1">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Text='<%# Bind("priceslist") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("priceslist") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Буду премного благодарен))

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1):

Заработало вот таким образом. Левый список заполняется сохраненными данными, а в правом подсвечиваются выбранные элементы списка. Теперь не знаю как сделать так, чтобы при помощи правого списка можно было редактировать левый как при вставке новых записей

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit || e.Row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate))
            {
                DataView dview = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
                breakslist = (String)dview.Table.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["breakslist"];

                for (int i = 0; i < breakslist.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (breakslist[i] != '<')
                    {
                        formItem += breakslist[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("ListBox6")).Items.Add(formItem);
                        formItem = "";
                        i = i + 4;
                    }
                }
                foreach (ListItem ItemToSelect in ((ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("ListBox5")).Items)
                {
                    foreach (ListItem SavedItem in ((ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("ListBox6")).Items)
                    {
                        if (ItemToSelect.Text == SavedItem.Text)
                        {
                            ItemToSelect.Selected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```